# Transitioning from WPF to Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

How hard is it to transition from WPF to Silverlight?

Would you say that a developer who knows WPF can pick up Silverlight with ease?

Comment: If you are developing for the web you can also publish your wpf applications as xbap so you might not need to learn silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly easy to pick up Silverlight if you know WPF.  There are some subtle differences, but most of the concepts apply.

The largest stumbling block is dealing with things that are unsupported in Sliverlight.  You often need convoluted workarounds for things that are easy in WPF but unsupported in Silverlight (such as [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things to get used to is the browser that sandboxes your Silverlight Application. Of course you can use the out-of-browser version and that opens quite a few options but it will still not be like WPF.

You might miss the full .NET functionality you are used to in WPF but the Silverlight runtime is pretty rich.